# Manually create Liferay login url

Tags: javascript, url, liferay

Is there a way to create a Liferay login url if I know the site name, virtual host, username, etc...

I basically want to come up with some javascript that enables third-party sites to create a login box to my site, preferablty to a specific page

Just to clarify, I need a url that will log in the user with the parameters they type in text fields on the third party site. The third party site does not necessarily use Liferay so it cannot have a login portlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you need...

Do you need http://virtualhostname/c/portal/login page?

Or you what to create a your own login page... e.g. creating a page with just the LOGIN portlet and provind a link to open it in Exclusive mode?

Or something else...?

Comment: The third party website the user will log in from will most likely not run Liferay so they can't add a login portlet

Comment: I'm saying that, creating a page with login portlet only, you can provide that link (in exclusive windowstate) to the other website... and it can embed the portlet inside a popup/iframe o what you need. Try adding parameter like "p_p_state=exclusive" to the page containing login portlet.

Comment: Yep, I did it that way

Answer (score 0):

In a Liferay portlet, put that piece of code :

```
            LiferayPortletURL urlLogin = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(
                    request, "58", themeDisplay.getPlid(),
                    PortletRequest.ACTION_PHASE);
            urlLogin.setWindowState(LiferayWindowState.EXCLUSIVE);
            urlLogin.setParameter("_58_struts_action", "/login/login");
            urlLogin.setParameter("_58_login", _your_login);
            urlLogin.setParameter("_58_password",_your_password);
            urlLogin.setParameter("_58_rememberMeCheckbox", "false");
            urlLogin.setParameter("_58_redirect", _write_an_url_to_be redirected_after_successful_login);
            urlLogin.setParameter("_58_doActionAfterLogin", "false");
            urlLogin.setParameter("_58_saveLastPath", _your_previous_url);
```

58 is the portletId of the Liferay Login portlet.
Then, have a look at your urlLogin.toString() to understand how is it build.

Regards

Comment: I did that but the username/password are encrypted so I can't just set them as parameters in the url